# SSIS - XML File location on DataFlow task is "losing" path

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

I have a situation in SSDT 2015 that sounds like this: The flow is to process some XML files, split the information into the relevant tables according to the XSD schema and then insert into production `database` and finally, delete the files that have been already processed.

I have used a `Foreach Loop Container` and specified the folder where my XML files will be physically and then pass it to a variable.

[image]

Then, if I close SSDT and open it again, I get an error that the file previous file processed is missing...

[image]

I have tried to recreate DataFlow task and the I have generated the XSD schema several times, deployed the package but I don't know what else to do.

Does anyone know any tips?

**EDIT**

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you look in the folder specified in the error message, is the file there?   You aren't telling us much about what the actual problem is...should the file be there, or should the package be looking for a different file?

Comment: @TabAlleman - in the specified folder in the error message, I might have a lot of XML files, that's why I'm using `ForeachLoop`. The point is that after processing one file with success and delete it, it should go to the next file within the folder, but is still looking for the file previously processed.

Comment: The problem could be either in your foreach loop's variable mappings, or in the xml source/connection.   Can you add screenshots of those?

Comment: @TabAlleman - I edited my post

Comment: So it looks like your XML source has a hard-coded location instead of using the variable that you populate in the foreach loop, unless I'm missing something.